# How can I retrieve datetime object through Python webscraper?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to build a simple webscraper from one of the websites that scrapes the articles' titles and their time of publishing on the website.

I've been able to access the titles of the articles but I have no idea how to access the object 'datetime' from the html from this website. Can anyone help? This is the code I have written and certainly there's something wrong with the last line as its output is 'none'. I also attached a snippet of how the html looks like for this website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

url = "https://www.invisibleoranges.com/"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
releases = soup.find_all('article', class_='')

for release in releases:
    print(release.find('a', class_="title").get_text())
    print(release.find('time', class_='').get('datetime'))
```

[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0D6I.png)

Comment: If you go to the webpage's source, `time` has nothing. It is rendered using JavaScript.

Comment: You may have to use selenium for this, I tested it and as said above because of javascript requests and bs4 won't work.